# Как написать НЕ со словом ВИДИМЫЕ?

Tags: орфография

Над головой хрипло орали (НЕ)ВИДИМЫЕ за листьями птицы.
Есть правило, что отглагольные прилагательные на -МЫЙ пишутся с НЕ раздельно, если образованы от переходного глагола несовершенного вида и употреблены с зависимым словом в Тв.п.
Почему в ответе к заданию сказано, что слово "невидимые" в этом предложении пишется слитно? Действительно, хочется написать слитно. Но как это объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что не любой творительный подходит - нужен так называемый творительный орудия. Например, не видимый (кем?) - указывает на лицо, которое не видит; не любимый (кем?) мною. С предлогом "за" (кем? чем?) уже нет значения лица.

Творительный инструментальный (орудийный) указывает на орудие, посредством которого совершается действие. *Писать карандашом. Рубить топором. Пахать трактором.*

*Над головой хрипло орали невидимые за листьями птицы.*

---

[Как пишется правильно: «невидимый» или «не видимый»?](https://orfographia.ru/nevidimyy-ili-ne-vidimyy-kak-pravilno/)

> Прилагательное пишется слитно, когда заменяется синонимом или
> выражением, близким по значению. Например: невидимый – скрытый.
>
> Пишется раздельно, если есть противопоставление с «а» или наречия,
> усиливающие отрицание: «далеко», «вовсе», «отнюдь», «никому»,
> «ничуть», «ни в чём». Пример: никому не видимый; враг не видимый, а
> спрятанный.
>
> Следовательно, написание выражений «невидимый» и «не видимый» зависит
> от контекста предложения и может быть как слитным, так и раздельным.

Comment: Благодарна Вам за объяснение!